# How to send mail gmail via smtp?

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm receiving an exception when trying to execute this mail-sending method.

> {"Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: "}

my code:

```
public async static Task SendExceptionMail(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO: fill..

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("other_email_than_my_email@gmail.com");
            message.From = new MailAddress("my_email_in_gmail@gmail.com");

            message.Subject = "Server Exception Occured";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Exception occured. Stack trace:");
            sb.AppendLine(e.StackTrace);
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("Time: " + DateTime.UtcNow);

            message.Body = sb.ToString();
            message.IsBodyHtml = false;
            message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my_email_in_gmail@gmail.com", "very_very_complicated_password_with_numbers_and_signs");
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Port = 465;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                //smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                
                
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

In my Gmail account, I allowed IMAP and POP in the settings tab.

What I've tried:

- Changing the port to 587 and 25. this time I'm getting `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at`
- commenting/uncommenting the `UseDefaultCredentials` line, the `DeliveryMethod` properties
- commenting/uncommenting the `IsBodyHtml` and `BodyEncoding` properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to follow this - [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1) and [Cannot send mail from certain server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f2a855ad-7e08-4108-8ecb-6c546a27e4d5/cannot-send-mail-from-certain-server?forum=csharpgeneral)

-First Check whether "[Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)" is enable in google account setting then check with below code:

```
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my_email_in_gmail@gmail.com", "very_very_complicated_password_with_numbers_and_signs");
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Port = 587; // Google smtp port
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;// disable it
                /// Now specify the credentials 
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(message.From.Address, fromPassword)

                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
```

There may be some firewall issue .

References:
[SendEmail in ASP.net shows me Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: Dovecot ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440952/sendemail-in-asp-net-shows-me-syntax-error-command-unrecognized-the-server-res)
[Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750861/syntax-error-command-unrecognized-the-server-response-was)

Hope this help.

Comment: if i haven't noticed my code, the code you provided is exactly the same as mine.
And yes, before i posted this question i also read those answers, no help with that. Though i haven't linked any ip with gmail, just set the settings i've mentioned

Comment: have you tried by specifying credentials and Turn On Access for less secure apps in the gmail account?

Comment: i coudln't find the section where i can choose what kind of access i allow to the accout. i only activated IMAP and POP,  according to the answer in the topic you gave me, it's no longer where they say it is

Comment: Ok, i found where. please update your answer with the link : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
also the port should be 587 after that. ill accept this answer

Comment: @OriRefael - I have updated port but i am still working with port 465 and already enabled setting in my google account. it is still working fine.. It's good that you have solved your issue.

Comment: well, if you find anything with 465, keep me posted, its more secure i think

Comment: Am I correct that that code is setting `smtpClient.Credentials` twice? If that is necessary then it is sure bizarre.