# Async Email throwing a Syntax error asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, email

When I run my app locally and click send on my contact form, I receive this error

> Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was:
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Syntax error, command  unrecognized. The server response was:
>
> Line 65: await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

I'm fairly new to creating contact forms. I'm using my gmail account to send details from user back to my mail

```
smtp.Credentials = credential;   
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

smtp.Port = 465;   // SHOULD BE 587

smtp.EnableSsl = true;   
await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);   
return "sent";
```

Thanks in advance!

```
[SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: ]
   System.Net.Mail.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +1885147
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result) +31
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result) +49
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
```

Comment: Have you provided your Gmail credentials in the request?

Comment: Hi Rory, Yes I did using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())   
{   
var credential = new NetworkCredential
{   
UserName = "", // replace with sender's email id   
Password = "" // replace with password   
};

Comment: Please post the full *exception* including its call stack. You can get this with `Exception.ToString()`. The correct port for GMail though isn't 465, though, it's 587.  The correct settings *are* mentioned in [Google's site](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en). Google for "GMail SMTP". Google no longer uses TLS, the same as all major sites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# sendmail gmail smtp syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126731/c-sharp-sendmail-gmail-smtp-syntax-error)

Comment: Mr Kanavos! you were right! this syntax error was caused by using port 465!
The correct port that worked was port 587

Thank you, I read up on that now! I appreciate it